# c# change datagrid cell color

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i am trying to change color of a datagrid cell but only in c# not by xaml.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="arcad_Grid"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="252" Margin="822,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Loaded="getArcadVersion" AutoGenerateColumns="true" SelectionChanged="Choicecontrol" SelectionMode="Extended" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionUnit="Cell"  />
```

is there an other way of doing it via c#?
any help would be appreciated

Added the Whole part Getting the Data from the Database and filling it with the DataGrid

```
   try
        {
            conn.Open();


            string cmd = "DSPOBJD OBJ(QSYS/DIID*) OBJTYPE(*LIB) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(Arcad_V)";
            OdbcConnection odbc = new OdbcConnection("DRIVER={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)};SYSTEM=XXXX;TRANSLATE=1;XDYNAMIC=0;CONNTYPE=0;DBQ=XXXX;UID=XXXX;password=XXXX");

            string as400cmd = "CALL  QCMDEXC('" + cmd + "')";
            OdbcCommand odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(as400cmd,odbc);
            odbc.Open();
            odbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            string SQLquery = "select ODOBNM,ODOBTP from Arcad_V ";
            iDB2Command comm = conn.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandText = SQLquery;
            iDB2DataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                arcad.createspoolfile(reader[0].ToString());
             if (arcad.couleur == "rouge")
                {
                    DataGridCell cell = GetCell(0,0,arcad_Grid);
                    cell.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                }
                if (arcad.couleur == "vert")
                {
                    DataGridCell cell = GetCell(0, 0, arcad_Grid);
                    cell.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                }

            }

            iDB2DataAdapter adp = new iDB2DataAdapter(SQLquery, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("DIIAB.Arcad_V");


            adp.Fill(dt);
            arcad_Grid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: could you display your xaml file?

Comment: @Frenchy Added the datagrid line

Comment: What happen when you try to use your code ? Do you have an error ?

Comment: no errors but  it's not what i wanted because it  colors all of the grid.all i want is when my variable couleur = red or green it colors the cell Reader[0].toString(); and i dont know how to do that

Comment: so  if i understant you you want to change the color only for one cell?

Comment: yes want to change the color for 1 cell @Frenchy

Comment: ok its better with the way you load the datagrid..!!

Comment: yes ^^ my bad i didnt put it earlier

Comment: @Frenchy did you found any solution ?

Comment: yes but its complex using a converter..in fact following the content of the cell you adapt the background color?

Comment: see my solution its okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new sample with some data: you have to use a converter with multibinding to do waht you want..

mainwindows.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <WpfApplication1:HighlighterConverter x:Key="myHighlighterConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="arcad_Grid" Loaded="arcad_Grid_Loaded" SelectionChanged="arcad_Grid_SelectionChanged" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True" SelectionUnit="Cell" >
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myHighlighterConverter}" >
                                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"></Binding>
                                    <Binding Path="Row"></Binding>
                                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

during the loaded event in mainwindow.xaml.cs:

```
    private void arcad_Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Color", typeof(string));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", "rouge");
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", "vert");
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", "rouge");
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", "vert");
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", "vert");         

        arcad_Grid.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
    }
```

converter.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class HighlighterConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values[1] is DataRow)
            {
                var cell = (DataGridCell)values[0];
                var row = (DataRow)values[1];
                var columnName = cell.Column.SortMemberPath;

                if (row[columnName].ToString() == "rouge" )
                    return Brushes.Red;
                if (row[columnName].ToString() == "vert")
                    return Brushes.Green;

            }
            return SystemColors.AppWorkspaceColor;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Another solution with a simple converter: you add this in converter.cs

```
public class ValueToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string input;
        try
        {
            DataGridCell dgc = (DataGridCell)value;
            System.Data.DataRowView rowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)dgc.DataContext;
            input = (string)rowView.Row.ItemArray[dgc.Column.DisplayIndex];
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException e)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
        switch (input)
        {
            case "rouge": return Brushes.Red;
            case "vert": return Brushes.Green;
            default: return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

modification in mainwindow.xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <WpfApplication1:ValueToBrushConverter x:Key="ValueToBrushConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource ValueToBrushConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="arcad_Grid" Loaded="arcad_Grid_Loaded" SelectionChanged="arcad_Grid_SelectionChanged" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="True" SelectionUnit="Cell" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}" >           
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

same result with less coding

Comment: it says my DataGrid doesnt contains definitions for Rows

Comment: could you display how you are loading the datagrid?

Comment: i edited my initial post with the whole part of code with getting the data from the db and loading in the  datagrid because it wouldnt let me answer my question @Frenchy